# Python - Redis/Lua cannot decode serialized data

Tags: python, lua, redis

my second time asking question here. So please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I am trying to solve this puzzle: 
I have JSON Object coming into my Python server, I parse it for Python to use(works fine and great) then I make a Dictionary: `{foo=0, bar=1236, taz=6}`

and I've been trying to make a List out of those Dictionaries, to pass along to Redis/Lua logic to figure out.

So what I've tried to do is to Serialize that list(and I've tried to serialize dict by itself) into MessagePack or JSON object and pass it alone to Lua for it to decode it. But every time I try to decode it - I get an empty Lua table.

Python snippet:

```
for item in incoming_list:
    lua_dict = dict()
    lua_dict['foo'] = 1
    lua_dict['bar'] = 555
    lua_dict['taz'] = 4
    lua_list.append(json.dumps(lua_dict))
    # Sending data to Lua 
    lua_script(args=lua_list, keys=[key1, key2, ...])
```

In Lua with JSON:

```
for i=1, table.getn(ARGV) do
    local element = cjson.decode(ARGV[i])
    table.insert(test_table, element)
end
```

In Lua with MessagePack:

```
for i=1, table.getn(ARGV) do
    local element = cmsgpack.unpack(ARGV[i])
    table.insert(test_table, element)
end
```

Every time I look at `test_table` it is empty, or `{{}, {}, {}, {}, ...}`

What is my mistake?

Comment: How do you call Lua?

Comment: I have a script handle stored in python so I'd do `lua_script(keys=[key1, key2], args=[arg1, arg2])`

Comment: Lua* not LUA Please fix this

Comment: Are you passing `lua_list` as one of your arguments? You either need to encode the list (not just its elements), or you need the elements of the list (not the list itself) to be the arguments.

Comment: Also, [use](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#7.2) `#ARGV` instead of `table.getn(ARGV)`.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - Sorry I should have included that to the question. The way I pass Lua list is `lua_script(args=lua_list, keys=[key, key,key])`. I did try it both ways encode single element and just give Lua list of encoded Hash Tables, or encode full list of hash tables - results are the same.